# Superscript "^oC" in ylab in ggplot -

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to plot "^oC" but keep getting an error: "Error: unexpected '^' in "ggplot"
However if I place "R^{o}C" is works. See code snippets below. The first code does not work the second works but not useful with "R" in ylab.

`ggplot(MD15, aes(DateTime,Temp/100))+geom_point(position="jitter")+labs(title="Phase 3 - March 2012") + ylab(expression(Temp~(~^{o}~C)))`

`ggplot(MD15, aes(DateTime,Temp/100))+geom_point(position="jitter")+labs(title="Phase 3 - March 2012") + ylab(expression(Temp~(R^{o}~C)))`

Looked around and tried several suggestions but none work.
If this has been answered a link would be appreciated.
Thanks!
Vince

Comment: Of course, there exists a symbol for degrees, °.

Comment: your example is neither minimal nor reproducible

Answer (score 23):

```
qplot(1,1) + ylab(expression("today's temperature is "*-5~degree*C))
```

Comment: Thanks baptiste ...it workde! Can't vote up because I need > 15 reputation...but I clicked on the up-arrow several times anyway:)

Comment: try an _odd_ number of hits