# superscription of only one character within brackets on an axis label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want my x label to be: `Latitudinal extent(0)`, with the *zero* inside the brackets superscript (i.e. the degrees symbol).
I can't find a way of doing it.

Currently, this works:

```
xlab(expression(Latitudinal~extent~(.^0~.)))
```

but then I need to erase the extra dots using Paint (or something similar).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391903/superscript-oc-in-ylab-in-ggplot or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404248/r-how-to-get-superscript-in-text-with-a-bracket-before-the-superscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the degree symbol, why don't you use the degree symbol?

```
plot(1, xlab = expression("Latitudinal extent"~(degree)))
```

A superscript zero is possible but doesn't look good:

```
plot(1, xlab = expression("Latitudinal extent"~({}^0)))
```

You might want to study `help("plotmath")`.